# How to stick text to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a line "All Rights Reserved..." at the bottom of the page.
I tried to use absolute positioning, but this does not work as expected when the window resized to smaller height.

How can I achieve this simple goal ?

Comment: What exactly "does not work as expected"?

Comment: Any code exmaple we can work with?

Comment: What do you mean with "bottom of the page"? For that you would just add it at the bottom of the HTML code. But it seems that you want it to be placed at the bottom of the *window* rather than the page. (if the page is scrolled or the window is resized, it should always stick to the lower window border. (Is that what you want?)

Comment: I think your'e after the answer at this one. The footer div will be under all other divs even when you resize your browser window. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351674/how-to-make-a-div-expand-to-fit-available-vertical-space/2351714#2351714

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You might want to put the absolutely aligned div in a relatively aligned container - this way it will still be contained into the container rather than the browser window.

```
<div style="position: relative;background-color: blue; width: 600px; height: 800px;">    

    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; background-color: green">
    TEST (C) 2010
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28):

Try:

```
.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Try this

```
 <head>
 <style type ="text/css" >
   .footer{ 
       position: fixed;     
       text-align: center;    
       bottom: 0px; 
       width: 100%;
   }  
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="footer">All Rights Reserved</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I edited it to make it work, keeping the idea of making it in the centre, since I also needed it. Hope other people will find it useful too.

Comment: Px is not necessary if it is equal to 0, why add extra bytes when you don't need to? :)

Answer (score 9):

From my research and starting on this post, i think this is the best option:

```html
<p style=" position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; text-align: center;">This will stick at the botton no matter what :).</p>
```

This option allow resizes of the page and even if the page is blank it will stick at the bottom.

Comment: I liked this solution!

Comment: This really worked for me. The simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I've done it.

```css
#copyright {
 float: left;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="copyright">
  Copyright 2018 &copy; Steven Clough
  </div>
```

Comment: If I click "Run code snippet", this is shown at the top of the page, not the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

An old thread, but...Answer of Konerak works, but why would you even set size of a container by default. What I prefer is to use code wherever no matter of hog big page size is. So this my code:

```
<style>
   #container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
 }
 #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
 }
</style>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

 <div id="container">

    <h1>Some heading</h1>

<p>Some text you have</p> 

<br>
<br>

<div id="footer"><p>Rights reserved</p></div>

</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The trick is in `<br>` where you break new line. So, when page is small you'll see footer at bottom of page, as you want.

BUT, when a page is big SO THAT YOU MUST SCROLL IT DOWN, then your footer is going to be 2 new lines under the whole content above. And If you will then make page bigger, your footer is allways going to go DOWN. I hope somebody will find this useful.