# Displaying a number at bottom-right with a background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a container with the dimensions of 26x26 pixels and display a number at the very bottom right of this container. In addition, I would like to add a background 24x24 picture to the container.

The code I have so far is as follows

```
<html>
<style>
body {
    height:26px; 
    width:26px; 
    background-color:red;
}
#bottom {
    vertical-align:bottom; 
    text-align:right; 
    background-color:yellow;
}
</style>

<body>
    <p id="bottom">2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's a JSFiddle link to make things easier https://jsfiddle.net/n8ku715x/

As you can see from JSFiddle, it is not entirely working. It's not even setting the right dimensions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810262/how-to-stick-a-text-to-the-bottom-of-the-page   this seems what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<style>
  body {
  }
  
  #ctn {
    height: 26px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 26px;
    position:relative
  }
  #bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #fff
  }
  

</style>

<body>
  <p id="ctn"><span id="bottom">2</span></p>
</body>
```

Here's your container, with the number within it - is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

CSS

```
.container{
width:26px;
height:26px;
position:relative;
background-color:red;
}
.container-number{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="container-number">2</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add bottom 0 and position to the class if u wants the fixed

**CSS**

```
#bottom {  
    background-color: yellow;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}
```