# JLabel not displaying HTML correctly

Tags: java, html, css, swing, user-interface

This question is a follow up from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319071/displaying-a-number-at-bottom-right-with-a-background-image/38319153#38319153)

I have a JLabel with HTML text inside it. However, the HTML content it is not being displayed correctly. The JLabel is supposed to be 26x26 pixels with a number being displayed at the bottom right. My code doesn't seem to be displaying the number in the correct position, and its height seems to be truncated.

Here is my code:

```
final String buffBadgeStyles = "<style>" 
+ "#container {height:26px; width:26px; background-color: red; position:relative;}" 
+ "#bottom {position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;}" 
+ "</style>";

buffSlot_6 = new JLabel();
buffSlot_6.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
buffSlot_6.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
buffSlot_6.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
buffSlot_6.setText("<html>" 
+ buffBadgeStyles 
+ "<body>" 
+ "<p id=\"container\"><span id=\"bottom\">2</span></p>" 
+ "</body></html>");
buffSlot_6.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 12));
panel_playerBuffs.add(buffSlot_6);
```

The JLabel is meant to look something like this 
[image]
But my code is generating this [image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: 1) Swing's implementation of HTML/CSS is very basic. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Why are you using HTML. You can control the text position with properties of the label. Read the API for methods to control the horizontal/vertical position of the text.

Comment: @camickr Because I also need to add a background image centered in the middle of the label. The JLabel API doesn't allow strings to overlap images.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo, `I also need to add a background image centered in the middle of the label.` - well that information should be part of the question so we can  provide a proper solution. I still can't tell if you want the text painted on top of the image (at the bottom/right) or outside of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get this view by using a helper panel (that is wrapping the label) and choosing a proper layout for the panel. This way you don't need html. You should set 26 px size to the wrapping panel instead of label.

```
package so;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label test");

            JPanel helperPanel = new JPanel();

            frame.setContentPane(helperPanel);
            helperPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JLabel buffSlot_6 = new JLabel();
            buffSlot_6.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            buffSlot_6.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            buffSlot_6.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            buffSlot_6.setText("2");

            buffSlot_6.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 12));
            helperPanel.add(buffSlot_6, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setSize(100, 100);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea I was trying not to resort to this method. I thought there would be a simpler solution. Anyhow, thank you.