# How do I make a DIV fill the page, without "position: absolute;"?

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm trying to design a page layout that has a couple of headers, some main content, and a footer.

I want to use jQuery UI tabs widget in the main content with a border around it, so the div MUST fill all the space between the headers and footer, but also I want the content to expand if needed, off the bottom of the screen and a scrollbar appear so I can scroll down and view it.

Effectively, I want the minimum height of the content div to be the distance between the header and footer, but allow it to expand.

[I've implemented](http://jsfiddle.net/bg100/Atjxc/3/) the [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) method, which would work really nicely if I didn't want a border around my main content. In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bg100/Atjxc/3/) example the div with the red 2px border needs to initially fill the page, and when you click the "Add Stuff" button to add more content which goes off the bottom of the screen it needs to push the footer down and show a scrollbar.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

...with these rules:

- Content needs to have a border.
- Content needs to start off by filling the space between header and footer.
- Content needs to grow beyond the bottom of the page, showing a scrollbar.
- Footer needs to be pushed down as content grows.
- Use only CSS, so that if content changes dynamically, everything adjusts automatically.
- Work in modern browsers only, I'm not interested in supporting IE<8.

I've tried:

- Absolute positioning, but this fixes the content to the size of the screen and doesn't allow it to expand past the bottom.
- jQuery positioning, but this feels too much like a hack, and seems to be a bad way to fix it.
- Using `height: 100%` and `min-height: 100%` in various places, but doesn't seem to achieve what I want.
- Looking at other [Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10464716/180215) around the same problem, but none of them seem to account for the content growing beyond the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Your not going to find anything on this because it doesnt exist. You would have to use JS.

Comment: @Alex: that's what I feared, but I still have hope that someone may know of some secret undocumented way of doing this!! After all, I'm not asking for some weird and wonderful bizarre layout.

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with is http://jsfiddle.net/Atjxc/6/

Because the height of the window is variable, I had to use percentages *only*, along with absolute positioning.

```
.foo { overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; left:0; top:10%;
width:100%; height:85%; }
.footer{ background:#ffc; position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```

I added a container for the main part, which shows a scrollbar when the content gets too long. I couldn't put borders because they have to be set in px values, and it messes up my percentage-based heights.

Comment: Thanks, it's something I hadn't thought of, but its still not what I want really. I'm not keen on the scroll bar on just the content div. I want the user to 'feel' like they're scrolling the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You could just measure the actual distance that is between the header and footer, then set the min-height to that exact px.

like for eg, the distance between is 600px,

then set

```
min-height:600px;
height:100%
```

In this way, when you have content that fits way under min-height eg. 600px then the height shall be 600px, now when the content is added and it grows out of the 600px height, then the container div shall elongate in height to accommodate the added content which is covered by height:100%; .

And yeah, you can use "Measure It"(its a chrome/firefox extension) to measure the onscreen distance on the fly, its more convenient.

Hope this helps, and heres the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Atjxc/11/

Comment: Great idea, but how do I account for users with different resolutions, monitor sizes and browser window sizes?

Comment: look I wouldn't bother going any deeper than this (actually sorry for that), but for your help, I may wish to point you to this question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271675/jquery-screen-resolution-height-adjustment  This should suffice, and then you can change the 'min-height' attribute's value depending on {vertical screen res~ - (the header height + Footer height)}.