# Make Html elements fit vertically

Tags: html, css

How can I make Html elements fit the vertical space?
This is what I want to achieve: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/98YRH/) but **without specifying elements heights**.

PS: I know how to do this with JavaScript, looking for a HTML/CSS solution.

Thanks

**Edit after answers:**

I want to keep this effect working (is already working) but without JavaScript, because is already consuming a lot of processor.
The effect: The title bar and the window content fit the total window space, for each window in my 
 [demo website](http://ilyeskooli.com/jqdesktop/).

Thanks

Comment: This previous post may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351674/how-to-make-a-div-expand-to-fit-available-vertical-space

Comment: I deleted my answer, I thought you asked a different question. If I get anything useful I'll answer again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **ba-resize** jQuery plugin, you can make your code lighter by increasing the **delay** option of the plugin, (default is 250)

Answer (score 1):

I found this works. But you should change the percentage of top and bottom to fit your site. http://jsfiddle.net/98YRH/11/

Comment: Yes I know. That you I suggest you to calibrate the percentage of top and bottom of the element to fit your site. However, at least, it works without setting height of the element...

Comment: This is basically my issue, I don't know which one is taller, top or center div..

Comment: It sounds like your site is dynamic with content. I suggest using Javascript is better.

Comment: Here is my site:http://ilyeskooli.com/jqdesktop/. Try opening some windows, the title bar and the content of each window must fit the window size, now is working, but I'm using JavaScript (becasuse windows are resizable, and I am using a *heavy* script that triggers height change event) For this reason, I'm looking for a CSS solution

Answer (score -1):

I asume that by fit the vertical space you mean stretch the bottom of the browser if so you need to write in the css,

```
html {
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: i am sorry i dont get what you are trying to do, why do you need to do it without specifying the heights.

Comment: Because the content of the divs are dynamic (if top div have more content will be taller, otherwise the other div will be taller)