# Expand div vertically to available space

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page with 3 div on top of each other but I cannot get the middle content div to use all the vertical space available on screen. Note that top and bottom height cannot be fixed and that it has to be compatible with IE9.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Top</div>
    <div class="content">Middle</div>
    <div>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I also put that on Fiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/quaxkq40/

Thanks.

Comment: are the heights of top and bottom div fixed?

Comment: Specify clearly what you want to have, maybe with an example

Comment: @JayantVarshney I updated my question. The top and bottom div size are  not known.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351674/how-to-make-a-div-expand-to-fit-available-vertical-space

Comment: Is your container height fixed?

Comment: @Ucodia - Why don't you go with the css "100vh" rather than 100% on the container? It works, but that will have the content to be slightly larger than the available space. You can then do a CSS calculation to fix it if you know the height of the top and bottom elements. eg: height: calc(100vh - (total height of top and bottom elements));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If flexible box layout is an option, it can be done simply by displaying the container as a flex box and the nested `<div>`s as flex items:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Top</div>
    <div class="content">Middle</div>
    <div>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Note: Vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity.

---

Otherwise, you'll probably end up with CSS tables:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.container > div {
  display: table-row;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Top</div>
    <div class="content">Middle</div>
    <div>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Each of the above methods has its own pros/cons, choose one that meets the requirements with care.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to work in IE9 so no flexbox :/ I am gonna try with CSS tables.

Comment: @Ucodia Just make sure that the container has a `width` of `100%` as well. It is needed to make it fill the entire horizontal space — as we have changed the default display type of the element to `table`.

Answer (score 2):

You could display the div's inside `.container` as table rows.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.container>div {
    display: table-row;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/quaxkq40/9/)